# Figure out database deadlock

Tags: java, mysql, sql, innodb

I'm trying to write a `springboot` code to update the **wallet balance** based on the **DEBIT/CREDIT** transactions.
I've two tables viz. **wallet** and **transaction** for that.
I'm running a test suite which runs 100 parallel transactions (50 DEBIT and 50 CREDIT). About 50% transactions are failing with the following error, and also the wallet balance in **wallet** *table* is not matching the transactions stored in the **transaction** *table*

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

I am not able to figure out following
 1 )Why Deadlock
 2 )Why wallet balance is not matching the number of transactions successfully stored. I'm
using MySQL InnoDB for database

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
  public Transaction saveTransaction(String walletId, Txn txn) {
    Optional<Wallet> byId = walletRepo.findById(Integer.parseInt(walletId));
    if (!byId.isPresent()) {
      throw new WalletNotFoundException();
    }
    Wallet wallet = byId.get();
    Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
    transaction.setAmount(txn.getAmount());
    transaction.setType(txn.getType());
    transaction.setWallet(wallet);
    BigDecimal balance = applyTransactionToWallet(txn, wallet.getBalance());
    Transaction save = transactionRepo.save(transaction);
    wallet.setBalance(balance);
    return save;
  }

  public Optional<Wallet> getWallet(String walletId) {
    Optional<Wallet> byId = walletRepo.findById(Integer.parseInt(walletId));
    return byId;
  }

  private BigDecimal applyTransactionToWallet(Txn txn, BigDecimal amount) {
    if (txn.getType() == TransactionType.CREDIT) {
      return amount.add(txn.getAmount());
    }
    return amount.subtract(txn.getAmount());
  }
```

Comment: This is really not a great way to handle anything financial. Always, *always* use a ledger to record transactions. If properly designed then `SUM(balance) WHERE wallet_id=?` on the transactions table will give you the current balance for any given wallet. What you have here appears to have a singular `balance` column with no ledger, meaning you have no idea how that balance amount came to be.

Comment: it's just a practice project, and not an actual app.

Comment: Exactly why you should learn how to do it properly. It's not that hard, and it avoids the locking issue you're having because the ledger is basically append-only, there's no record-level contention.

Comment: But, let's say a wallet has too many entries in the ledger, then for each read request, I'm going to have to evaluate the ledger, which might be expensive

Comment: With the right indexes that's usually super quick, even with "lots" of entries. MySQL needs near zero time to sum up thousands of numbers.

Comment: Please show us the generated SQL, including the `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`.  Also provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table(s).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the deadlock by using `findByIdInWriteMode` instead of `findById` at the line below.

```
 Optional<Wallet> byId = walletRepo.findById(Integer.parseInt(walletId));
```

I changed my repo to

```
@Repository
public interface WalletRepo extends JpaRepository<Wallet, Integer> {
  @Query(value = "FROM Wallet W where W.walletId = :id")
  @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
  Optional<Wallet> findByIdInWriteMode(@Param("id") Integer id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want 100% immediate consistency, you could explore the functional locking concept where you will keep the wallets involved in one transaction in a functional locking table. So every transaction at the beginning will check if there is any functional lock on the wallet, if so wait till it can get the functional lock otherwise insert into the functional lock and proceed with the transaction.  Adding entries in functional lock table should be atomic with its own commit. And at the end of transaction, remove the locking entries.

If you are looking for eventual consistency(consistency with a delay), you can look to queue the transaction updates and daemons can process the queued items one by one, again using functional locking concept to avoid multiple daemons processing the transactions for the same wallet.